# Anniversaries of members

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of members who are long-term, sometimes helpful in the chat, but not necessarily noted for their high rep.  I thought it'd be nice to show in some way the long-service of members.  We could remove them if they're inactive for more than a year, perhaps?

Anyway, my answer will be a CW, editable for anyone to update.  I've added a few early members that I know of for now.

Answer (score 5):

**2011**

*June*

- [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo)
- [hippetrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail)
- [Phelios](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/88/phelios)

*August*

- [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception)

*November*

- [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)